# Android - Simplify my code: Multiple buttons linked to one method

Tags: java, android, pdf, download, simplify

As the title says I am trying to get help simplifing my code.  I have multiple buttons, now only three while I test this out but I plan on having approximately thirty button choices.  Currently I have a very long section of code and I think it can be shortened drastically maybe using an array?  But I'm not sure how to implement it correctly.  IF anyone has done this before or has an idea please share!  Thanks to everyone!

```
public class myDL extends Activity { 

public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0; 
private Button startBtn; 
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog; 

/** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.filechoice); 
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(myDL.this); 
mProgressDialog.setMessage("The file is now downloading, it will be saved on the SD card for future use.  Please use WiFi to avoid operator charges."); 
mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false); 
mProgressDialog.setMax(100); 
mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL); 

Button section = (Button) findViewById(R.id.section); 
section.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

    public void onClick(View view) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        Intent section = new Intent(view.getContext(), 
                section.class); 
        startActivity(section); 

    } 
}); 

Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back); 
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

    public void onClick(View v) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        setResult(RESULT_OK); 
        finish(); 
    } 
}); 

secOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.secOne); 
secOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        startSecOne(); 
    } 

}); 
} 

private void startSecOne() { 
StartSecOne secOne = new StartSecOne(); 
secOne 
        .execute("www.website.com/document.pdf"); 

} 

class StartSecOne extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> { 

@Override 
protected void onPreExecute() { 
    super.onPreExecute(); 
    mProgressDialog.show(); 
} 

@Override 
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) { 
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress); 
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]); 
} 

@Override 
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) { 

    String isFileThere = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
            + "/Android/Data/" 
            + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() 
            + "/files/test1.pdf"; 
    File f = new File(isFileThere); 

    if (f.exists()) { 
        showPdf(); 
    } else { 

        try { 

            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]); 
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection(); 

            connection.connect(); 
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength(); 
            int tickSize = 2 * fileLength / 100; 
            int nextProgress = tickSize; 

            Log.d( 

            "ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + fileLength); 

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream( 
                    url.openStream()); 

            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
                    + "/Android/Data/" 
                    + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() 
                    + "/files"; 
            File file = new File(path); 
            file.mkdirs(); 
            File outputFile = new File(file, "test1.pdf"); 

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile); 

            byte data[] = new byte[1024 * 1024]; 
            long total = 0; 
            int count; 
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) { 
                total += count; 
                if (total >= nextProgress) { 
                    nextProgress = (int) ((total / tickSize + 1) * tickSize); 
                    this.publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength)); 
                } 
                output.write(data, 0, count); 
            } 

            output.flush(); 
            output.close(); 
            input.close(); 
            mProgressDialog.dismiss(); 
            showPdf(); 

        } catch (Exception e) { 
        } 
    } 
    return null; 
} 
}
secTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.secTwo); 
secTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        startSecTwo (); 
    } 

}); 
} 

private void startSecTwo () { 
StartSecTwo secTwo = new StartSecTwo (); 
secTwo 
        .execute("www.website.com/document2.pdf"); 

} 

class StartSecTwo extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> { 

@Override 
protected void onPreExecute() { 
    super.onPreExecute(); 
    mProgressDialog.show(); 
} 

@Override 
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) { 
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress); 
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]); 
} 

@Override 
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) { 

    String isFileThere = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
            + "/Android/Data/" 
            + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() 
            + "/files/test2.pdf"; 
    File f = new File(isFileThere); 

    if (f.exists()) { 
        showPdf(); 
    } else { 

        try { 

            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]); 
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection(); 

            connection.connect(); 
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength(); 
            int tickSize = 2 * fileLength / 100; 
            int nextProgress = tickSize; 

            Log.d( 

            "ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + fileLength); 

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream( 
                    url.openStream()); 

            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
                    + "/Android/Data/" 
                    + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() 
                    + "/files"; 
            File file = new File(path); 
            file.mkdirs(); 
            File outputFile = new File(file, "test2.pdf"); 

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile); 

            byte data[] = new byte[1024 * 1024]; 
            long total = 0; 
            int count; 
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) { 
                total += count; 
                if (total >= nextProgress) { 
                    nextProgress = (int) ((total / tickSize + 1) * tickSize); 
                    this.publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength)); 
                } 
                output.write(data, 0, count); 
            } 

            output.flush(); 
            output.close(); 
            input.close(); 
            mProgressDialog.dismiss(); 
            showPdf(); 

        } catch (Exception e) { 
        } 
    } 
    return null; 
} 
}

secThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.secThree); 
secThree.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        startSecThree (); 
    } 

}); 
} 

private void startSecThree () { 
StartSecThree secThree = new StartSecThree (); 
secThree 
        .execute("www.website.com/document3.pdf"); 

} 

class StartSecThree extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> { 

@Override 
protected void onPreExecute() { 
    super.onPreExecute(); 
    mProgressDialog.show(); 
} 

@Override 
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) { 
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress); 
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]); 
} 

@Override 
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) { 

    String isFileThere = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
            + "/Android/Data/" 
            + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() 
            + "/files/test3.pdf"; 
    File f = new File(isFileThere); 

    if (f.exists()) { 
        showPdf(); 
    } else { 

        try { 

            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]); 
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection(); 

            connection.connect(); 
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength(); 
            int tickSize = 2 * fileLength / 100; 
            int nextProgress = tickSize; 

            Log.d( 

            "ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + fileLength); 

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream( 
                    url.openStream()); 

            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
                    + "/Android/Data/" 
                    + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() 
                    + "/files"; 
            File file = new File(path); 
            file.mkdirs(); 
            File outputFile = new File(file, "test3.pdf"); 

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile); 

            byte data[] = new byte[1024 * 1024]; 
            long total = 0; 
            int count; 
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) { 
                total += count; 
                if (total >= nextProgress) { 
                    nextProgress = (int) ((total / tickSize + 1) * tickSize); 
                    this.publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength)); 
                } 
                output.write(data, 0, count); 
            } 

            output.flush(); 
            output.close(); 
            input.close(); 
            mProgressDialog.dismiss(); 
            showPdf(); 

        } catch (Exception e) { 
        } 
    } 
    return null; 
} 
}



private void showPdf() { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    mProgressDialog.dismiss(); 
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
            + "/Android/Data/" 
            + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() 
            + "/files/test1.pdf"); 
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager(); 
    Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
    testIntent.setType("application/pdf"); 
    List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, 
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY); 
    Intent intent = new Intent(); 
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file); 
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf"); 
    startActivity(intent); 
} 


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final OnClickLisener listener = new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v){
         switch(v.getId()){ 
         case R.id.zero:
            break;
         case R.id.one:
            break;
         case R.id.two:
            break;
         }
     }
}
final int[] btnIds = new int[]{R.id.one, R.id.two, R.id.zero};
for(int i = 0; i < btnIds.length; i++) {
    final Button btn = (Button)findViewById(btnIds[i]);
    btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: good one! to improve on that, you can also avoid all those long findViewById calls by adding android:onClick="onClick" property to all those buttons in the layout xml.